# In the function $f(x) = 3x^{2/3}−2x$, the absolute minimum in the interval $(-1,1)$ is $x=0$ even though $x$ is not a critical point. Why?

Tags: calculus

In the function $f(x) = 3x^{2/3}−2x$, the absolute minimum in the interval $(-1,1)$ is $x=0$ even though $x$ is not a critical point. The first derivative of this function is $f'(x) = 2x^{-1/3} - 2$, which only gives a critical point of $1$.

On a graph, I can see that the graph comes to a point at $x=0$, so I don't understand why getting the critical points doesn't give me it. Why is this, and how am I supposed to work out that the answer (the absolute minimum) is $x=0$?

Comment: Your function isn't differentiable at $x = 0$. At this point, a subdifferential can be evaluated and it contains 0. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative

Comment: Well $0$ is a critical point ! Indeed, the definition states that it is either a point where the function is not differentiable or a point where the derivative is zero. Note that extrema can also be reached on the border of the domain (i.e. in $\pm 1$) without being critical points.

Comment: @zwim ok, so supposing I started the question as I did yesterday, asking for the minimum in this interval, with no knowledge of the answer. My usual process would just be to equate the first derivative with zero and work out the critical points. How, then, should I alter the process so that I would come upon zero as the answer?